# Winnovative HTML to PDF converter Justify text

Tags: c#, html, pdf, winnovative

I use winnovative 11 for converting HTML to PDF. My problem is that if I have a div element with the "text-align: justify" style, the library doesn't justify the element into a PDF. 
Reading the documentation I saw that there is the TextElement Class with a HorizontalTextAlign attribute.(but I can't find any demo) I have to use it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the latest version? It should have been a temporary issue with that old version you are using which has been fixed in the meantime because the latest version works well.

Comment: unfortunately not. I have the license key for the V11

Comment: In this case you should consider upgrading to the latest version. You can check the latest version in demo mode if you don't use a license key.